# How could I do calculations in a Stored Procedure?

Tags: c#, sql-server, r, database, database-design

I have a database that will handle thousands of rows used to store statistical data of an AI algorithm I coded for a Battleship game for a project I'm doing using C# as my programming language.

Should I do the calculations of, for example, average misses, average shots etc on the SQL Layer?

If so, should these be stored in the database under their own column? Or should they be calculated when running a query (or using the R programming language) that calculates the averages and not be stored anywhere?

I ask this question because I never used a database for such reason and I am not sure how to structure it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on what you are doing.

Pro stored procedures:

- if you have different clients accessing the same back end functionality they can all share the same backend code reducing duplication
- under same scenario it helps ensure consistency
- if your client code involves many back and forth accesses to the database server then the associated latency can be avoided by moving the code to the server in a stored procedure

Pro front end:

- easier to port to a new database
- easier to debug and backup -- with stored procedures you may need specialized software and you may need to pay for it even if the database itself is free but this is much less likely if you do it all in the front end
- overall simpler and less learning curve for developers
- if the code that would have been on the server is on the client instead then it is distributed over possibly many machines (one per client) avoiding bottlenecks on the server.

Answer (score 0):

What you "should do" can be a matter of personal preference, but if it were me, I would do the calculations you mention in the stored procedure that returns the data.  I would not store averages as columns in the database.

Answer (score 0):

it depends on would you like to reuse those records in the future or any further analysis depends on those data. If you do, you could get those derived value and store them into database, which will save the system I/O resource when your C# code runs, but in return, it will take some extra space. On the contrast, if you do not do such a way, it will not be a huge system burden if you do not have lots of computed field, and you could save the disk space as well.

Above all, it depends on your real world case.

Update: If using database, may also have the system resource issue, you need to `open` connection to target database, which may take some resource to do that.